# Updating state in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I am trying to update my state in ReactJS.  To do this I have an input field in a Reactjs class.  The field is automatically filled in with data from a parent class.  The field looks like this:

```
           <input
            onChange={e => this.props.store.addLego(e)}
            name="piece"
            value={this.props.row.original.piece}
          />
```

The addLego function is designed to update my state and is in a MobX store.  It looks like this:

```
 addLego = action("addLego", e => {
this[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
});
```

However, I can't actually edit the input field!  Nothing changes in the field when I type!  Thanks for your help!

Comment: you have the value set to `this.props.row.original.piece`, the only way for the value of the input as you see it to change would be to update the value of `this.props.row.original.piece`.

Comment: the value of `this.props.row.original.piece` needs to change as a result of your `onChange` function. As long as that value doesn't change, the value in the input won't change.

Comment: Actual you're not updating the state of your component, but some store? Why not:
 <input
            onChange={e => this.setState({inputValue: e.target.value})}
            name="piece"
            value={this.state.inputValue}
          />

Comment: Have you checked the developer console for any Javascript or React exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

If you set a `value` attribute to an `<input>` field that field becomes a controlled input. This means that whatever gets passed to `value` is rendered on the screen. In your case, if you are not updating `this.props.row.original.piece` the `<input>` field will never get a new value. I'll suggest to read this bit of React's documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

It is basically suggesting to keep the new value somewhere (in the component's state for example) and set it back as a value to the field.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) here will solve your problem. It's a good read too for handling single or multiple inputs

Basically, you'll need a state in the constructor

```
this.state = {value: ''};
```

Event handler to set the value every onchange

```
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }
```

And the setup for input

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

Comment: Don't forget to bind this.handleChange.bind(this) in the constructor.